# How to create a Web app to call phones from pc

Tags: cloud, sip, voip, telephony

I am new to cloud telephony. How can I develop a software that can make calls from pc to phone without using twilio and all.I am particularly confused, how this will be done because how can I call a phone number from an an Ip address. What will be the essentials required and how should I do it or how should I get started ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question where there are lots of answers.

On the browser side you need to use something like WEBRTC or some custom browser extensions to be able to communicate between the two endpoints, on top of that you build your VOIP protocol. For example you could design your own (e.g. skype), or use a standards based one like sip or some sort of hybrid.

Once you have voice (and/or video) between two endpoints going, you can then think about gatewaying your communications out to external systems.  There are a number of ways to do it.  If you can gateway your communications into a SIP based system then you can use a PSTN voice gateway hareware or a software SIP trunk gateway.  This will depend on what area of the world you host hour servers and what telecommunications companies offer and may depend on the amount of traffic you will be using as well.

There are lots and lots of moving parts with lots of pitfalls.  Too many to cover here.